# Why is the worst-case complexity of deleting the last element in an array O(1) and not O(n)?/?

Tags: arrays, time-complexity

If we have an array `A` of `n` `int`s, and we want to delete the `int` at `A[n-1]`, how would we do so exactly?

My professor claims that the worst case complexity for this operation is `O(1)`, but I'm confused on how to "properly" delete the element. I personally would *not* just write `0` in `A[n-1]` because that's technically overwriting it with `0`.

My idea was to create a new array `B` with `n-1` elements and copy the first `n-1` elements over from `A`, which would create a complexity of `O(n)` to complete the deletion, but this is apparently not the correct answer.

Can someone shed any insight to this?

Comment: Depends on what notions of "array" and "delete" you're working with. With classic arrays, there's no such thing as deleting elements.

Comment: It was probably assumed that the array was fixed-size, in which case "deleting" the last element of the array is equivalent to setting the last element to 0, etc. If your array is dynamically sized (i.e. can change size depending on capacity needs,) this is a different problem. Since get/put operations for fixed-size arrays are `O(1)`, the statement of "deleting" the last element being `O(1)` is correct in this context.

Comment: If your elements are not primitives, you can set A[n-1] = null; that would be  just freeing up some memory, but the array will always have 'N' elements which is what you initialize.

Comment: @ChrisSprague An array is not dynamically sized, arraylist is dynamically sized.

Comment: @svasa in Java, yes, but the terminology depends on the context you're talking about. A dynamically-sized array is still a kind of array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do n = n-1, you are no longer tracking the last element which is same as deleting the last element (Though it is still there in memory, but it can be overridden later) , making it O(1).

Comment: I was hoping there'd be a more "elegant" solution to deleting the last element than just *forgetting" about it in memory, but it seems not. Thanks! :)

Comment: In case of static array, I don't think its possible. But in case of dynamic array , you can do that.